# Reverse image search image protection

Tags: image, algorithm, search, image-processing, search-engine

I was wondering how to protect my images for image search reverse services like http://tineye.com/

Can they algorithm be faked?

If I for example buy image from DepositPhotos can I apply some color filter or other filter in Photoshop not changing original image too much 
but to prevent reverse search my image has downloaded from DepositPhotos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that any computer software you run, can be run in the opposite direction by companies that make a living from finding these kind of things.

I know that the guys at [PicScout](http://www.picscout.com/) do lots of stuff to find these things.
Unless you invent an algorithm all these companies are unaware of - not much you can do.
Come to think of it, even if you do invent something, it's just a matter of time until they get a complaint, figure it out, and then find it...

Comment: I think that TinEye and other similar software's are not 100% correct in finding exact images.

Comment: I am 100% sure they aren't. That ain't the point. THe point is that any out-of-box algorithm (e.g. well known stuff that photoshop uses) is probably known to them + they have their own algorithms. And, mainly, if they come across an unknown algorithm (due to a complaint form a user), they'll just figure out the idea, and add into their algorithm. It's a classic cat and mouse situation

Comment: The fact an algorithm is known and easy to invoke in one direction does not imply it can be easily done in the reverse. Everyone can find the RSA encryption of some data, and if you know that RSA was used, you are going to need the key in order to find the original. So, it basically nullify the logic used here. That said, I have no background in image processing and I have no idea if there is similar procedure for images.

Comment: You are forgetting that unlike in an RSA encrypted code, the original code (the original picture) is known to all parties... They can run the algorithm on the original picture and compare the result with what you have.

Comment: The RSA code is also known to all parties, only the secret key isn't. Maybe there is a way to add noise in a similar way that cannot be reproduced? (I have no idea if this is the case for image processing)

Comment: I think that in this case, since they are trying to see if your picture is like the original one, the idiom is that they have the RSA public key, the private key, the date is was created, where why and how...